Ordering complex numbers compatible with the product
I'm looking for a total order relation in $\mathbb C$  that is compatible with the product but not necessarily with the sum. I haven't been able to find one! Of course, we know that there doesn't exist a total order relation in  $\mathbb C$ that is compatible with both operations: addition and multiplication.
My question is : Can we Show that there doesn't exist an order  relation $\succ$ between complex numbers such that

(i) For any two complex numbers $z,w$, one and only one of the following is true: $z\succ w,w\succ z,$ or $z=w$


(ii) For all $z_1,z_2,z_3\in\mathbb{C}$ with $z_3\succ 0$, then $z_1\succ z_2$ implies $z_1z_3\succ z_2z_3$.


By compatibility, do you mean in this sense? If so, think about what happens if $z = -1$... If not, you should say exactly what you have in mind.

I added a clarification

Are you definitely not requiring $\succ$ to be transitive? (If not, better not to describe it as a total order)

don't understand, I want an order relationship, and an order relationship is by definition transitive

OK - it's just that you didn't mention transitivity after "My question is:...", just that $\succ$ is a trichotomous relation. Anyway, can't we take any total order $\succ$ such that $0 \succ z$ for all $z \ne 0$, as then (ii) is vacuously satisfied?

Any linear ordering that has $0$ as largest element (so $z_3 > 0$ is always false) satisfies your requirements.

Thank you, I added order relation. I will think about the suggestions

:@mihaild Can you give me an example of a total order $\leq$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that for every nonzero complex number $z$, $z \leq 0$.

@Noname take your favorite injection $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$, and say that $a \geq b$ iff $a = 0$ or $b \neq 0$ and $f(a) \geq f(b)$.

ok, thank you so much
